# Tree Data Structure OOP Design Problem (C#)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop, tree

I have a tree structure design problem, and i can't think of a way out.

i want to have one class Tree containing a generic data, and extend the Tree class with ComplexTree that will contain more methods like Iterate, DoSomthingOnComplex, etc.

here is a sample of the code i have:

```
class Tree<TData>
{
    public TData Data { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tree<TData>> Children { get; private set; }

    public Tree<Data>(TData data)
    {
         // ...
    }

    public void Iterate(Action<TData> action)
    {
         action(Data);  
         Children.ForEach(x => x.Iterate(action));
    }
}

class ComplexTree<TData> : Tree<TData>
{
    public int ComplexValue1 { get; set; }
    public int ComplexValue2 { get; set; }

    public ComplexTree(TData data, int cv1, int cv2)
        : base(data)
    {
         // ...
    }

    public void DoComplexStuffOnTree()
    {
         // ... might want to use the base methods here
    }
}
```

problem is that for one thing, i can't really expose the collection that holds Tree to anyone that has create ComplexTree and i can't use Iterate for the ComplexTree because i can't use the cv1, cv2 values that belong only to the inheriting tree.

is there an obvious solution i'm missing?
should i not use inheritance?
should rewrite all the methods?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Obvious question: If you want to add values to be stored in each node, why not just declare TData as a small class with a few properties?

Comment: I'll add that `DoComplexStuffOnTree` doesn't necessarily have to be a method of `Tree` or any of its children. It's an algorithm that's orthogonal to the implementation of the tree.

Comment: Stevem already said it, but define class ComplexData that holds those 2 complex values, then ComplexTree : Tree<ComplexData> so that TData becomes ComplexTree - then you can call Iterate or whatever on the base and it works fine

Comment: yes, i agree that all the methods i'd like to add are algorithms but we can all agree that each node in a tree is in itself a root of a tree and so i'd like to be able to use tree.DoSomething and not algorithms.DoSomthing(tree). but that  leaves me with wondering why should i inherit from tree<data> anyway, since all the methods are in algorithms class the complex tree... i'm still not sure/convinced.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question without knowing the actual use-case you need the tree structure for, but in general I would take sides with the suggestions made in the comments:

- Declare a class `ComplexData` containing your two ints and declare `ComplexTree` as a subclass of `Tree<ComplexData>`.
- You could even declare `ComplexData<TData>` itself generic so it can contain an additional `TData`, and then declare `ComplexTree<TData>` as a subclass of `Tree<ComplexData<TData>>`.
- You need to be clear on the *code contract* for the methods that run your algorithms — i.e. what is the method actually supposed to do, in general/abstract terms, not in terms of a particular use-case. If the contract is that it returns a collection of `TData` objects, then obviously that is what it should do, *irrespective* of whether you are running it on a simple tree or a subclass. If the contract is more abstract and the behaviour should depend on the subclass, then maybe it should be a virtual method (or use protected virtual methods) that the subclasses can override.